# Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active in Phalcon

Tags: php, stored-procedures, phalcon

I have gone through lots of post from StackOverflow and other sites. Following is the solution which I found almost on all sites But its not working for me. :-

```
     return new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\MySql(array(
            "host"     => 'XXXx',
            "username" => 'XXXX',
            "password" => 'XXXX',
            "dbname"   => 'XXXX',
            "options"  => array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true)
        ));
```

My code for calling Store Procedures:

```
    public function AssignPromoterToPromotionVenuAction($bookingSheetID = 0, $promoter_id = 0, $userID = 0)
    {
        $query = "CALL `x_wf_AgencyAssignPromoter`($bookingSheetID, $promoter_id, $userID)";
        $rp = new Promotion();
        return new Resultset(null, $rp, $rp->getReadConnection()->query($query));
    }

    public function RemovePromoterToPromotionVenuAction($bookingSheetID = 0, $promoter_id = 0, $userID = 0)
    {
        $query = "CALL `x_wf_AgencyRemovePromoter`($bookingSheetID, $promoter_id, $userID)";      
        $rp = new Promotion();
        return new Resultset(null, $rp, $rp->getReadConnection()->query($query));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution :

instead of returning a Resultset you can fetch the result of calling the procedure:

```
 return $rp->getReadConnection()->query($query)->fetchAll();
```

[Ref Link](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10366#issuecomment-103077259)